# C# stored procedure won't save data

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, stored-procedures

I've written a stored procedure to store my form data, while I'm not getting any error yet my data won't save in database.

Code:

```
private void doneBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SampleDatabaseWalkthrough.Properties.Settings.SampleDatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                cn.Open();

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.InsertOrder", cn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", SqlDbType.Int);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductId", null);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderQuantity", double.Parse(qtyAmountL.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", null);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderDate", today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tax", double.Parse(taxAmountL.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total", double.Parse(totalAmountL.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Net", double.Parse(subtotalAmountL.Text));

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                cn.Close();

                MessageBox.Show("Successfully saved");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        StringBuilder errorMessages = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < ex.Errors.Count; i++)
        {
            errorMessages.Append("Index #" + i + "\n" +
                "Message: " + ex.Errors[i].Message + "\n" +
                "LineNumber: " + ex.Errors[i].LineNumber + "\n" +
                "Source: " + ex.Errors[i].Source + "\n" +
                "Procedure: " + ex.Errors[i].Procedure + "\n");
        }

        Console.WriteLine(errorMessages.ToString());
    }
}
```

And here is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertOrder]
    @Id int,
    @ProductId int = NULL,
    @OrderQuantity int,
    @CustomerID int = NULL,
    @OrderDate varchar(50),
    @Tax int,
    @Total int,
    @Net int
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Orders (Id, ProductId, OrderQuantity, CustomerID, OrderDate, Tax,Total, Net) 
    VALUES (@Id, @ProductId, @OrderQuantity, @CustomerID, @OrderDate, @Tax, @Total, @Net)
END
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it hitting the Successfully Saved line?

Comment: @devlincarnate yes it does

Comment: what is this: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", SqlDbType.Int); should be an INT value, right?

Comment: @urlreader I was trying to generate ID

Comment: the exception probably is not SqlException , so did not catch it

Comment: @urlreader but it does hit `MessageBox.Show("Successfully Saved");` so it's not going to catch part at all

Comment: Do you have a connectionstring with the substitute shortcut _DataDirectory_?

Comment: Echo Steve's comment; my initial thought is that you're looking in the wrong database. To test this, on the line before you have cn.close() put: `var dt = new DataTable(); var da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from orders", cn); da.Fill(dt);` then put a breakpoint on `cn.close` and when the code stops point to `dt` and click the magnifying glass; do you see your data?

Comment: The AddWithValue must receive the Parameter Name and it's value. You're setting the name and the type.

Comment: @RobertoOSantos you mean for id? How should I generate id then?

Comment: You dont generate id; you let the db do it - set its Identity SPecification to auto increment / seed 1 step 1 and leave it alone. Don't mention it in your insert statement at all and it will autogenerate. If you want to know what id was generated you can finish your stored procedure with `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` and executescalar your sproc instead

Comment: @RobertoOSantos but the enum passed in is a value no less.. and essentially an integer one at that! :)

Comment: Still not getting an answer about the connectionstring/datadirectory clarification request.

Comment: @Steve sorry couldn't make it ( newbie :/ ) but I figured the issue is coming from my `double` values that are supposed to be `int` apparently I am getting values for `tax` or `total` like `16.500` instead of `16500`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you use AddWithValue,  you need the right conversion, insted of

```
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tax", double.Parse(taxAmountL.Text));
md.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total", double.Parse(totalAmountL.Text));
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Net", double.Parse(subtotalAmountL.Text));
```

should be

```
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tax", Int32.Parse(taxAmountL.Text));
md.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total", ConvertTo.Int32(totalAmountL.Text));
.....
```

or better

```
 if (Int32.TryParse(subtotalAmountL.Text, out int numValue))
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Net", numValue);
else ....return error
```

also should be

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductId", DBNull.Value);
```

UPDATE

Since I have received some question this needs more details.

It was just a hint, my point is that value should be integer type.

for example if you format the value like "16,500" this is working

```
int.Parse("16,500", NumberStyles.AllowThousands);
//or
Convert.ToInt32(double.Parse("16,500"))
```

it  is all depends at the culture info

Comment: with `ini.Parse()` I'm getting `Input string was not in a correct format.`

Comment: this is what causes your error. Check the string and try Int32. Parse(). ini is a typo

Comment: For instance with `Console.WriteLine(totalAmountL.Text);` I'm getting `16,500`.

Comment: It was just a hint. The value should have int type. String depends on the culture and formatting. you can try Convert.ToInt32(double.Parse(totalAmountL.Text)) for example

Comment: I think that `Convert.ToInt32(double.Parse(totalAmountL.Text))` works but I don't understand why I have 2 database in `SQL Server Object Explorer` data saves in one and not other one! so I cannot see stored data in my app

Comment: @mafortis and ideally, [stop using AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) completely.